# JPARepository JPQL @query ORDER BY (ERROR: expecting CLOSE, found 'null' )

Tags: hibernate, jpa, repository, hql, jpql

.im using JPARepository + Hibernate, and ihave the next query wuth a subquery that order sub-result by a number or registers found.

```
 @Query("SELECT t0 FROM TextFragment t0 WHERE t0.id = "
+ "(SELECT t.id FROM TextFragment t JOIN t.fragment f JOIN t.reactionsTextFragments r "
+ "WHERE f.parent.id = :idParent AND t.codStateTextFragment = '001' "
+ "GROUP BY r.textFragment ORDER BY COUNT(r.textFragment) DESC, t.updatedDate ASC)")
```

And i have the nex error

> Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting CLOSE, found 'null' near line 1, column 254 [select count(t0) FROM com.treebuk.model.TextFragment t0 WHERE t0.id = (SELECT t.id FROM com.treebuk.model.TextFragment t JOIN t.fragment f JOIN t.reactionsTextFragments r WHERE f.parent.id = :idParent AND t.codStateTextFragment = '001' GROUP BY r.textFragment]

Why the query doesn't read the ORDER BY clause and the final of Query? i dont understand...Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JPQL, a subquery cannot have an ORDER BY. As per the BNF

```
subquery ::= simple_select_clause subquery_from_clause [where_clause] [groupby_clause] [having_clause]
```

Consequently your query is invalid. Shame the error message doesn't state explicitly what the problem is though.

Comment: Ty for response Neil. but I dont understand as JPARepository resolves this problem. Any solution for this? i need do a subquery for filter registers. is the unique solition make the logic in code behind?

Comment: "JPARepository" is nothing to do with the JPA API. The JPQL language spec is very clear (and Hibernate is following it apparently) and ORDER BY is illegal in subqueries. Remove your ORDER BY

Comment: i can't remove order by, really i neeed a limit too for only get the register with more reactionsTextFragment.... i need a complex query..... I dont understant as JPA havent support for this.

Comment: You can't have a limit in subqueries either; please, at least read the spec on the technology you chose to use. If you want to use all sorts of SQL-specific features then use NATIVE SQL and lose database independence.

Comment: Sorry, im newby in Java, Sring, Hibernate, JPA... im making a complex proyect in this technology, and I try use it the best form that i know it... Simply, i try understand as resolve my problem in this point of the proyect... I have too much logic with Spring MVC, JPARepository and Hibernate.... Can I create a specific method using NATIVE SQL? or Is not possible?  How? what find?